# Invalid array assignment in a child process

Tags: c++, shell

I have a code for a custom-made "mini shell" in which I am parsing a string supplied by the user into individual words in the terminal in a child process.

The following is the child code:

```
child_pid = fork();

            if (child_pid == 0)
            {
                char* args[100];
                int   prev_pos = 0;
                int   pos;
                int   i = 0;

                cout << "Inside loop" << endl;
                while((pos = command.find(" ", prev_pos)) != string::npos)
                {
                    //cout << command.substr(prev_pos, pos) << endl;
                    if (i >= 1)
                    {
                        cout << endl << "Before Assignment: " << i - 1 << "   " << args[i - 1] <<"kwe"<< endl;
                    }

                    args[i] = const_cast<char*>((command.substr(prev_pos, (pos - prev_pos))).c_str());
                    cout << i << "   " << args[i] <<"befre cndition aftr ass"<< endl;
                    //cout << command.substr(prev_pos, pos) << endl;
                    if (i >= 1)
                    {
                        int j=i-1;
                        cout << "After Assignment: "<< i - 1 << "   " << args[j] <<"eefe"<< endl;
                    }
                    cout << i << "   " << args[i] << endl;

                    if (i >= 1)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                        {
                            cout << "\t" << j << "   " << args[j] << endl;
                        }
                    }

                    prev_pos = (pos + 1);
                    i++;

                }// 'while' loop


                args[i] = const_cast<char*>((command.substr(prev_pos)).c_str());
                cout << i << "   " << args[i] << endl;
                i++;

                cout << "Outside loop" << endl << endl;
                cout << *(args + 0) << endl << endl;
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    cout << j << "   " << args[j] << endl;
                }

                args[i] = NULL;

                cout << endl << endl << args[0] << endl << endl;
                //execvpe(args[0], args, envp);

                cout << "Unknown command\n";
                exit(0);

            }// 'if'
```

The **problem** is that whenever I assign a word of the input string to `args[i]`, all the values starting from index `0 to (i - 1)` also get assigned the same value. S**o, if the user enters, lets say, `ls asd dajd adakjs`, then I end up(at the end of the while loop) with all `args[i]`s having the value "`adakjs`"** as shown in the following output (the `cout` statements are just for debugging purposes):

> ```
> Inside loop
> 0   lsbefre cndition aftr ass
> 0   ls
>
> Before Assignment: 0   lskwe
> 1   asdbefre cndition aftr ass
> After Assignment: 0   asdeefe
> 1   asd
>   0   asd
>   1   asd
>
> Before Assignment: 1   asdkwe
> 2   dajdbefre cndition aftr ass
> After Assignment: 1   dajdeefe
> 2   dajd
>   0   dajd
>   1   dajd
>   2   dajd
> 3   adakjs
> Outside loop
>
> adakjs
>
> 0   adakjs
> 1   adakjs
> 2   adakjs
> 3   adakjs
>
>
> adakjs
>
> Unknown command
> ```

Why is this happening? And how can I modify my code so that at the end of the while loop, each of the words get stored into the arg[i]s? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line is this:

```
args[i] = const_cast<char*>((command.substr(prev_pos, (pos - prev_pos))).c_str());
```

The `substr` function returns a string object, of which you get a pointer, and then the string object is *destructed*, leaving you with a stray pointer to data that doesn't exist any more. This will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory for the strings to make them permanent.